# C# Attributes and Aop paradigm

Tags: c#, aop

I want to know the difference between the use of the C# custom Attributes and an AOP framework (like PostSharp).
How to choose between them ?

Comment: AOP is a programming paradigm, while attributes are an implementation detail of the C# (or any other language which uses them). They are on two different scales. One way to implement AOP is by using attributes, but AOP is a much broader concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom Attributes are ways of declaring metadata on elements of your code that are understood by other elements of your system, including things like compilers, AOP frameworks, validation engines etc...

PostSharp performs IL (intermediate language) weaving, e.g after compile it injects IL at certain points in your assembly based on configuration/attributes.  E.g you can add a Custom Attribute to a method, and during compile PostSharp will write IL to intercept this method and provide you with behaviour at runtime.

https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net/msil-injection

PostSharp is one way of implementing AOP, there are many others, including dynamic proxies (e.g Castle.Core) which can intercept methods at runtime by providing dynamic subclasses of the classes you are wishing to extend.

In both examples, attributes can give you a means of configuring the behaviour of these features

For example, you have a method:

```
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
     return x + y;
}
```

And you wanted to provide Logging or diagnostics for this method, by adding this code manually (log is a hypothetical logging API):

```
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
     log.Enter("Add", x, y);
     log.Leave("Add", x, y);
     return x + y;
}
```

You distract from the purpose of the method and it starts to muddy the water when considering method complexity and single responsibility principles.

Ideally you want to be able to add this behavior at runtime/compile time, and usually for more than a single method, this then becomes a cross-cutting concern, e.g you want to log everything.

So you end up needing a way to notify the system that you want to apply logging to the Add method.  A convenient way is to tag the methods with an attribute:

```
[Log]
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

We have added metadata to the Add method ([Log] Attribute) to indicate we want to log this method (and reverted back to a method that does not violate single responsibility principles), however by itself the attribute is relatively meaningless.

What is needed is something to interpret the custom attribute and provide the mechanism to intercept the method call and add the log.Enter, log.Leave calls.  This is where we choose something like PostSharp or Dynamic proxies, or other AOP frameworks.

Comment: Nice answer.  Might I suggest moving the paragraph "Custom Attributes are ways of declaring..." to the start of your answer?  That's really the crux of the issue here - attributes can be used for a wide variety of things, but don't *do* anything by themselves.  An AOP framework uses the attributes to actually *do* stuff.

Comment: postsharp is not free